# Immunity Debugger - !mona suggest

Tags: exploit-development

Potentially simple question. I have been going through some tutorials for exploit development that use !pvefindaddr for help with creating unique patterns and discovering the offset.

I know that mona has replaced pvefindaddr - but from what I can see in the examples I am following the:

```
!pvefindaddr suggest
```

Command gives you an exploit suggestion in perl, while:

```
!mona suggest
```

Basically writes you a metasploit module.

I looked at the options with:

```
!mona help suggest
```

And there don't seem to be many options available. Is it possible to get suggest to offer you exploits written in any format other than a metasploit module?
I couldn't seem to get pvefindaddr working in immunity - I'm assuming it doesn't really work anymore as mona has replaced it, so I wondered if mona had any flexibility?

Comment: I bet you will get better and faster answers at Reverse Engineering Stack exchange. - http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: or the Vulnerability Research and exploit development subreddit:  https://www.reddit.com/r/vrd   Good Luck!

Comment: Cheers - I had a look at reverse engineering stack exchange, but I thought this might come more under security as I'm not really reverse engineering anything as I understood it? My question is more about exploit development.

Comment: I'll definitely give it a go though, and thanks for the reddit pointer!

Comment: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13605/immunity-debugger-mona-suggest If anyone wants to see a comprehensive answer!

Comment: wow, they really  came through.